# Brush MVVM Binding does not give named color

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatrigger, brushes

I have a MVVM binding for Border background where in I read Color names from a file in String format and convert them to Brush using the code:

```
Brush b1 = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red");
myItem.Background = b1;
```

Background is a property defined in ViewModel as:

```
public Brush Background
{
    get { return _background; }
    set
    {
        this._background = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Background");
    }
}
```

And it is accessed in XAML as:

```
<Border Background="{Binding Background}">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background}" Value="Red">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

The border is properly colored- no issues there.

The problem is DataTrigger is never triggered because when I see the value of this._background in set method, it is "#FFFF0000" and it is not equal to Brushes.Red (i tried converting value to SolidColorBrush and then compared with Brushes.Red, but it is not equal).

What is that I am doing wrong? What can I do to ensure that the color names that I read from a file are properly converted into Brushes.* so that my DataTrigger works fine.

Thanks,

RDV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `Brushes.Red` is a `SolidColorBrush`. Not a color, a brush. Confusion arises from the implicit conversion of the string "Red", in the XAML, into a Brush object. But a new `SolidColorBrush` instance with a `Color` that is also equal to `#FFFF0000` will be a different instance of `SolidColorBrush`, and they won't be "equal" to one another.

But you don't care which brush instance it is; you care about the color. So compare the color. `(Brushes.Red.Color == Colors.Red) == true`. `Color` is a value type, not a reference type, so two equivalent *values* will be considered equal.

```
<DataTrigger 
    Binding="{Binding Background.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
    Value="Red">
```

Notice that `Background` isn't a property of the `DataContext`. That was a second thing that wasn't working with your code. You need to explicitly tell the `Binding` to look not at the `DataContext`, but at the control itself, to find the property referred to in the `Path`. `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` does that. `"Background.Color"` is the `Path` parameter for the `Binding`. `Path` is the default, so you don't have to explicitly name it. But you could:

```
<DataTrigger 
    Binding="{Binding Path=Background.Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
    Value="Red">
```